# creating buffer from array javascript meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, buffer

How can I retrieve records from my collection then create a buffer from that collection. The buffer will be uploaded to a different site:

```
var data = myCollection.find().fetch();
console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));   // outputs the collection as an array
var json_data = new Buffer(data);
console.log('json data: ' + JSON.stringify(json_data)); // weird buffer output
```

The second log statement outputs:

```
json data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

I have also tried using the new Buffer for Node.js but that doesn't seem to work:

```
var json_data = new Buffer(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a buffer from an arbitrary object like that. When you create a buffer out of an array, the constructor expect each element of the array to be an integer describing the byte value. Attempting to convert your collection item yields `NaN`, which is then casted to `0` byte value.

You can however create a buffer from the stringified data:

```
var json_data = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(data));
```

To easily check that your data is correctly converted to the buffer, convert it again to string before logging:

```
console.log('buffer content', json_data.toString());
```